# XML - group and merge elements, whilst keeping all element text

Tags: xml, bash, macos, xmlstarlet, xmllint

I have some XML where there are repeated elements with differing text. The repeated elements are both consecutive and non-consecutive. I am trying to merge the text from these elements, and remove the duplicate elements. The tool of choice is `xmlstarlet` (in `bash` on `osx`).

Input:

```xml
<wrapper>
 <data>
  <item_b>fun</item_b>
  <item_a>foo</item_a>
  <item_a>bar</item_a>
  <item_b>times</item_b>
 </data>
</wrapper>
```

Desired output:

```xml
<wrapper>
 <data>
  <item_a>foo bar</item_a>
  <item_b>fun times</item_b>
 </data>
</wrapper>
```

Comment: Thanks @CarlosCavero - to the best of my searches, I don't see this issue addressed explicitly in any other questions. I hoped that the input/output example I gave was clear - does it need improving?

Comment: @tesolat - Welcome to Stack Overflow. I agree; great first question +1. The only thing that would've made it better was if you had shown what you had tried; even if it wasn't close to giving you the output you wanted. Anything is better than nothing. :-)

Comment: Thanks! Initially did have a (bad) plan to use `perl` slurp mode to regex across rows and deal with it that, but I then got it in my head there was an `xslt` solution but didn't really know where to start with it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're very welcome. You were right; XSLT is a much better option than regex. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do is use the [xmlstarlet `tr` command](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139602800) to do the transform with an XSLT.

Then you can use [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to group the elements by name.

Example...

**XML Input** (test.xml; edited based on questions in comments)

```
<wrapper>
    <data>
        <item_b>fun</item_b>
        <item_a>foo</item_a>
        <ignore>bad</ignore>
        <item_a>bar</item_a>
        <item_b>times</item_b>
        <ignore>times</ignore>
    </data>
    <data>
        <item_a>Uh oh should be</item_a>
        <item_a>in own element</item_a>
    </data>
</wrapper>
```

**XSLT 1.0** (test.xsl)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="items" match="data/*" use="concat(generate-id(..),name())"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="*[not(self::ignore)][count(.|key('items',concat(generate-id(..),name()))[1])=1]">
        <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('items',concat(generate-id(..),name()))"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="data/*">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**xmlstarlet command line**

```
xmlstarlet tr test.xsl test.xml
```

**XML Output**

```
<wrapper>
   <data>
      <item_a>foo bar</item_a>
      <item_b>fun times</item_b>
   </data>
   <data>
      <item_a>Uh oh should be in own element</item_a>
   </data>
</wrapper>
```

Comment: if you encounter; "xmlstarlet: command not found" (and you do have _xmlstarlet_ installed), then change the command line to `xml tr test.xsl test.xml` instead - note `xml` instead of `xmlstarlet`

Comment: Thanks Daniel - I didn't know about Muenchian Grouping, which is a great help. With your solution, if I added two rows ( `<ignore>bad</ignore>` and `<ignore>times</ignore>`) they would also be grouped and merged. How do you explicitly control which elements the template acts on?

Comment: @tesolat - How you'd handle that would depend on whether there were more elements to ignore or more elements to specifically process. In your example there is only one element to ignore so I'd just ignore those by adding a predicate to `*` in the for-each. I'll update the example in my answer.

Comment: @tesolat - If you wanted to go the other way and specify the elements to process, you'd change `*[not(self::ignore)]` to `(item_a|item_b)`. (Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYii)

Comment: @tesolat - Was my update sufficient or are you still having issues? If it’s sufficient, please accept my answer by clicking the check mark next to it. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies for the delay - Need a little time to adapt it to my data!

Comment: Thanks for the patience! So, there's an issue with how your solution identifies uniqueness Daniel but it's likely my mistake in not framing the example properly. So, add a second `<data>` element, a child of which is an element called `<item_a>`.  In this case, the template will merge all the `<item_a>` elements, as well as the `<data>` element, when we want to limit the merge to the specific `<data>` element.  I've updated the Fiddle to illustrate this: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYii.

Comment: Sorry, here's the correct Fiddle link: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYii/1

Comment: @tesolat - In that case you can make a composite key by combining the generated id from the parent `data` and the name. See my edit and updated fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYii/3

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's XSLT solution will be the best one. However I like to get programming languages to care about the details of XML for me. Ruby is nice for dealing with XML:

```
gem install xml-simple

ruby -e '
    require "xmlsimple"
    data = XmlSimple.xml_in(ARGV.shift, {"keeproot" => true})
    items = data["wrapper"][0]["data"][0]
    items.each_key {|n| items[n] = [ items[n].join(" ") ]}
    out = XmlSimple.xml_out(data, {"keeproot" => true})
    puts out
' file.xml
```

```
<wrapper>
  <data>
    <item_b>fun times</item_b>
    <item_a>foo bar</item_a>
  </data>
</wrapper>
```

I see in the comments that you want to filter out some tags (put **all** requirements in your question!). Add this line *before* `items.each_key`:

```
    items.select! {|name, value| name.start_with? "item"}
```

Comment: Thanks @glenn-jackman. I won't accept this answer because I'm tied into `xmlstartlet`, but it's great to have a second approach documented on the thread. I'm sure others will benefit from it!